# confidence intervals versus probability bounds

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, mean, uncertainty

I performed a Monte Carlo simulation of a multi-input parameter system and generated a 95% Confidence Interval (CI) of the response output mean. The input parameters were all normally distributed with mean ONE and std. dev = 0.20. Data post-processing of the Monte Carlo runs showed that the 95% CI of the mean did not contain the baseline result when all input parameters = ONE, hence some confusion.

I can also generate probability bounds from the CDF of the output distribution. In this case, the probability bounds contain the baseline result (when all input parameters = ONE).

Can someone please elaborate when and where the 95% CI of the mean versus probability bounds from the CDF should be used for uncertainty analysis?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "baseline result" and how that is supposed to be related to your simulation?  Are you saying that this is the output when all inputs are set to their means?  If so, it will be instructive to contemplate a simple black-box system with one input $x$ (with a mean $E[x]=1$) and output $(x-1)^2.$  No matter what distribution $x$ might have, when you input the value $x=1$ the output is the *smallest* possible output of $(1-1)^2=0,$ not the expected output.  A good confidence interval for the mean of the output should *not* cover this "baseline result"!

Comment: Yes, the baseline result is the black-box output when all the input parameters are set at their mean value. In any case, I am also trying to understand for uncertainty analysis, when and where 95% CI of the mean should be reported as apposed to the 95% probability bounds from the CDF of the output from the Monte Carlo runs.

Comment: By performing enough simulations, you can make any CI of the mean (of any output value) as narrow as you like.  Thus, reporting a CI would be presenting results about your time, patience, or budget, rather than results about your subject of interest.